# A DELETE-statement that causes mySQL server instance shutdown?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

By holding months of redundant data, I'm trying to prune a database of mine. Unfortunately, the mySQL server instance (not the server itself) seems to be crashing when I run the query that I thought would remove unnecessary rows.

```
DELETE w FROM word w WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT NULL FROM translation t WHERE t.WordID = w.KeyID LIMIT 1
) AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT NULL FROM namespace n WHERE n.IdentifierID = w.KeyID  LIMIT 1
)
```

Is there a way where I might make this query more efficient?

**edit #1** Error from SQL Workbench: Error Code: 1053. Server shutdown in progress

**edit #2** The following query also fails, indicating that there has to be something wrong with gluing the tables together, perhaps?

```
SELECT w.* FROM word w
    LEFT JOIN translation t ON t.WordID = w.KeyID
    LEFT JOIN namespace n ON n.IdentifierID = w.KeyID
WHERE t.TranslationID IS NULL AND n.NamespaceID IS NULL
```

Using hard-coded values in the sub query works however:

```
SELECT w.* FROM word w WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT NULL FROM translation t WHERE t.WordID = 1
) AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT NULL FROM namespace n WHERE n.IdentifierID = 1
)
```

**edit #3** The table *word* contains words that is associated with each row in the tables *namespace* and *translation*.  A row in *word* might in other word be associated with one or more rows in both the *namespace* and *translation* tables. This is a means originally thought to prevent repetition of data and improve search performance.

Through months of renewing and deprecating data rows in both of the *namespace* and *translation* tables, there are words that are no longer in use. I want to delete these words, so that I might free up some space and deliver more relevant search results.

**edit #4** I am starting to think that this might be a time out error? I tried to change the query to the following:

```
DELETE FROM word WHERE KeyID NOT IN (
    SELECT WordID FROM translation 
    UNION
    SELECT IdentifierID FROM namespace
)
```

No avail.

As for indexes, an explain yields the following results

```
id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra
'1', 'PRIMARY', 'word', 'ALL', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '18430', 'Using where'
'2', 'DEPENDENT SUBQUERY', 'translation', 'ALL', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '28219', 'Using where'
'3', 'DEPENDENT UNION', 'namespace', 'ALL', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '7708', 'Using where'
NULL, 'UNION RESULT', '<union2,3>', 'ALL', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, ''
```

*word*: primary key on *KeyID* and an index key on the *Key* column.

*translation*: primary key on *TranslationID* and an index key *NamespaceIDKey*

*namespace*: primary key on *NamespaceID*

**edit #5** While it doesn't necessarily answer the question that I asked, the following brute-force query solved my problem. If the database had foreign keys however, this approach obviously wouldn't have worked, but still, here it is:

```
-- Push all relevant words into a temporary table
CREATE TABLE temp
    SELECT DISTINCT w.* FROM translation t
        INNER JOIN word w ON w.KeyID = t.WordID
    UNION
    SELECT w2.* FROM namespace n2
        INNER JOIN word w2 ON w2.KeyID = n2.IdentifierID;

-- Empty the table
TRUNCATE TABLE word;

-- Re-insert the relevant words
INSERT INTO word            
    SELECT * FROM temp;
```

Comment: Does it work if you hard-code in some rows for the sub-queries?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this query? Please provide details.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend consulting the server logs to understand why the server is shutting down.  If it's over-heating, for example, get that fixed!!!

Comment: @Dems: I took the question to be that MySQL is shutting down, not the entire O/S.

Comment: @MarcusAdams I've updated my original post with some more information. :)

Comment: It sounds like the server was shutting down anyway, I guess that's a red herring.

Comment: @Dems Yes, it is the instance that shuts down, not the server.

Comment: @eggyal - My bad, I think you're right.

Comment: Ah, sorry! I've updated my post and fixed the ambiguity.

Comment: @Zanathel - What indexes do you have on each table?  And are you able to include the EXPLAIN for the query?  If the `SELECT LEFT JOIN WHERE IS NULL` version is 'failing' it *feels* as though you don't have indexes that MySQL can make use of.

Comment: What error do you get from the LEFT JOIN query? If you get this working then you should be able to turn this into a DELETE, which will avoid using the 2 sub-queries and may be more efficient. The shutdown may be to do with MySQL running out of resources owing to the complexity of the statement. There's something similar reported causing shutdown of a node when MySQL is clustered [link](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=61496)

Comment: @Zanathel - Although you have resolved your immediate issue by working around it, it looks as though you *may* have described the cause in one of your edits; ***you are joining on fields that you have not indexed.*** Should you create the following two indexes, the queries will likely speed up significantly: `Translation(WordID)` and `Namespace(IdentifierID)`. Without these indexes MySQL is having to trawl the whole table to find a match. With the indexes MySQL can just seek out a match in a tiny amount of the time. If you join these tables by these fields anywhere else, you should index them.

Comment: @Dems That was actually the problem. The moment I added those indexes, the queries just took around 8 milliseconds to execute! I'm willing to accept this as an answer, if you'd add it below! :) Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you have resolved your immediate issue by working around it, it looks as though you may have described the cause in one of your edits:

- ***you are joining on fields that you have not indexed.***

Should you create the following two indexes, the queries will likely speed up significantly:

- `Translation(WordID)`
- `Namespace(IdentifierID)`

Without these indexes MySQL is having to trawl the whole table to find a match. With the indexes MySQL can just seek out a match in a tiny amount of the time.

If you join these tables by these fields anywhere else, you should index them.

Comment: But even if the columns are not indexed, the statement should not cause a shutdown of the server!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I've never actually used MySQL. But, from a brief google, MySQL apparently sometimes shuts down and re-starts if queries run for too long. If this is intended resource management I'd bet it can be configured, but I didn't look in to it. For now I'm content with "if it runs for too long you get this error, and adding indexes means it doesn't run for too long". *[Wierd way of handling server side command timeouts, but MySQL is wierd anyway ;)]*

Answer (score 1):

> Error Code: 1053. Server shutdown in progress

You can get this error when the connection to the MySQL server is interrupted. Its text is little misleading as only the connection was shutted down, not server.

For example I have cron job which kills long running SELECT statements to prevent server overload. When it kills the connection with mysql `KILL` command, the query returns also with this error.